# Maven generate zip instead of just WAR file

Tags: java, maven

Here's the plugin for maven WAR plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
   <configuration>
       <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        <webResources>
            <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What plugin can generate a ZIP file containing the same files in the WAR?

Comment: Why do you want a ZIP in place of a WAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a custom [assembly](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies.html) with the use of the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

The following descriptor declares an assembly of format `zip`. It uses a `<dependencySet>` to declare the dependency towards the WAR packaged by the Maven build. This WAR is unpacked so that the final ZIP has the exact same content has the WAR file.

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>zip</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:war:${project.version}</include>
            </includes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Save this file, [for example](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) in `src/assembly/assembly.xml`. Then, in your POM, you need to declare an execution of this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-zip</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When you invoke Maven with `mvn clean install`, this plugin will be executed and it will create the wanted ZIP file inside the `target` folder.